# Action of permutation operator on other operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition, notation

I'm watching MIT 8.06 Quantum physics, lecture $23.2$ *See for example [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaBMK5JSz2I&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60Zcz8LnCDFI8RPqRhJbb4L&index=94&t=376s)*  Particularly See $5:41$. It is shown that
$$P_{21}B(1)P^\dagger_{21}|u_i\rangle_1\otimes |u_j\rangle_2=|u_i\rangle_1\otimes |B u_j\rangle_2.$$
I have couple problem in definition of $B$ itself. It has been said, that $B\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{V})$. How does this operator which is in $\mathbb{V}$ can act on the product vector space? It's dimensionality itself doesn't match.

The usual definition that I have read is $\Gamma_1^{(1)}\otimes \Lambda^{(2)}_2$ when acting on the basis in product ket.

$$\Gamma_1^{(1)}\otimes \Lambda^{(2)}_2|\phi\rangle \otimes |\chi\rangle=|\Gamma^{(1)}_1\phi\rangle \otimes |\Gamma^{(2)}_2\chi\rangle $$
where $\phi$ and $\chi$ is used to show the label $1$ and $2$. Considering the same, How I can prove the previous result?

$$P_{21}\Gamma^{(1)}_1\otimes I^{(2)} P^\dagger_{21} |\phi_i\rangle \otimes |\chi_j\rangle =P_{21}\Gamma^{(1)}_1\otimes I^{(2)} |\phi_j\rangle \otimes |\chi_i\rangle =P_{21}|\Gamma^{(1)}_1\phi_j\rangle \otimes |\chi_i\rangle. $$
I don't know, what's going to happen next? It came to the same issue, How $B$ can act on either space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is to be understood that $B(1)$ is short for $B\otimes\mathbb{I}$ and $B(2)$ is short for $\mathbb{I}\otimes B$.

As far as I know, permutations are only defined for identical particles/states. Then you can just follow your lecture, but replace $B(n)$ with the appropriate definition from above. Let $|u_i,u_j\rangle = |u_i\rangle\otimes|u_j\rangle$.

$$P_{21}|B,1\rangle P^\dagger_{21} |u_i,u_j\rangle = P_{21}|B,1\rangle |u_j,u_i\rangle = P_{21}|Bu_j,u_i\rangle=|u_i,Bu_j\rangle=B(2)|u_i,u_j\rangle$$

Comment: Okay Got it! Thanks